# android recyclerview with GridLayoutManager childs height fit parent when 2 or less childs

Tags: android, height, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView changes child width when spanCount is changed:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
```

[RecyclerView with 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6SNk.png)

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
```

[RecyclerView with 1 column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OqH5.png)

My question is, is there any way to have the same behaviour but with height that allow me to fit child on parents height?

If you see the previus pictures, there is an space under the 2 items, but there are not more items on this RecyclerView. I want to use all the space with the current items.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateViewHolder the child view is created withing the ViewHolder. What I did is send to the ViewHolder constructor the parent (recyclerView) heigh and then in change the ViewHolder size:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list_item, parent, false);
    if(getItemCount()<3){
        return new ViewHolder(rowView, this.onItemClickListener,parent.getHeight());
    }
    return new ViewHolder(rowView, this.onItemClickListener);
}



 public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener onClickListener,int height) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.view.setMinimumHeight(height);
    }
```

this.view is the groupView.

I don't know it this is the best aproach, but for now works!